# iPad app transferred to different account, any way to keep keychain access

Tags: ios, app-store

We recently transferred app from one account to the other. Now, we'd like to update the app however Validating archive in Organizer reports:

"The application-identifier entitlement value has changed. The previous version of software has an application-identifier value of 'xxx' and the new version of the software being submitted has an application-identifier value of 'yyyy'. This will result in a loss of keychain access.

App depends on keychain being accessible. Any way to solve this?

Update:

Search for "keychain" in link below:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html

This one makes me think it is possible to keep keychain access.

This one does not (search for bold "Important"):
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2311/_index.html

Comment: Actually, a very valid question - but I would guess this is best asked directly to apple.

Comment: @LordT already sent the question to apple, waiting for answer...

Comment: Don't forget to also file a bug with Radar.

Comment: Good link there - Wanna file that as the answer? looks like (what I was expecting) it's not possible

Comment: What was Apple's response?

Comment: @Robert: from https://developer.apple.com/contact/ (second link at the bottom) - contact DTS. From DTS, please contact iTunes Connect Contact Us. From iTunes connect:Keychain will continue to work until an update to the app is made. To continue using keychain after an app update, the recipient must update the bundle information to include the Team ID and ensure that the keychain is correctly programmed.

Comment: Thanks for this - however, I am confused now! Does this mean if you configure the app correctly you can avoid loosing the keychain information?  All the other information seems to suggest you will loose access.

Comment: @Robert - no idea what it means, I asked for additional clarification - which is why I haven't updated this question yet...

Comment: @bh213 Going through the same process and got the same reply from iTunes Provider Support. Given the ambiguity, I called Apple on the number provided and after a long discussion, they are seeking further clarification. I will update with any info I receive but looks like you had success so fingers crossed!

Comment: Just to follow up, we were unable to find any way around losing keychain access.

Comment: @bh213: Did you submit a Technical Support Incident (TSI) from the Member center and then it got resolved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After I asked for clarification from iTunes connect us, I got email from devprograms@apple.com saying that they updated the App Bundle Id.

I was able to generate correct provisioning profiles and submit the update to app store without warnings. App hasn't been accepted yet but we were able to confirm that Ad Hoc version now works correctly when upgrading (it didn't before Apple update App Bundle id).

Note that I am member of both dev teams - the team where app originated and the one where the app was transferred to. Not sure if this made any difference.

Comment: I have spoken with a Senior iTunes Provider Support representative and he confirmed a one time loss of keychain data is expected behaviour and that it was not possible to change the Team ID. In contrast to bh213, I do not have access to the iTunes Connect account from which the app was transferred.

Comment: When asked, the representative said it was theoretically possible to transfer the app back to the originated iTunes connect account and so the Team ID would be restore and thus keychain data would not be lost. However, he stressed it was "uncharted waters" so may/may not work.

Comment: I want to transfer an App to another account. The Prefix this App has right now is not the current Teams Id. Its something different. So if i understand your answer correctly it should be possible to just transfer the app and then ask Apple to "transfer" the Prefix aswell right? Then it should be possible to create the same App Id and there should be no loss. Could you confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

See Apple [Technical Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1726/_index.html)

> Q:  How do I resolve the Potential Loss of Keychain Access warning?
>
> A:  Apps that should expect this warning and proceed with the
>   submission regardless are:
>
> 1. Those that are migrating their App ID prefix from an arbitrary Bundle Seed ID to their more-modern Team ID as documented in Technical
>      Note TN2311 - Managing Multiple App ID Prefixes.
> 2. Those that are submitting the first update for a recently acquired app via App Transfer.

I would think 2. applies to your case.  Apple also has a [note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2311/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014135-CH1-A_ONE_TIME_LOSS_IN_KEYCHAIN_DATA_WILL_OCCUR_IF_YOU_SWITCH_YOUR_APP_ID_PREFIX) that it's not possible for a transferred app to maintain access to the prior keychain associated with the App ID prefix of the previous owner.

Answer (score -2):

Your only option is to continue using the old application identifier.

Comment: that won't work, as the team part is used for the keychain access, not just the bundle identifier!