# Does Apple remove keychain data of app when app disturbitor changed via tranferred app?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

In AppStore when an app transferred to different account and new account publish new version, does Apple remove app's keychain data due to encryption?

Thank you.

Comment: Check this discussion: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/41052 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24475203/ipad-app-transferred-to-different-account-any-way-to-keep-keychain-access

Comment: I have read this before but I read it again as you commented. I wouldn't be sadder in my  life after my app's user have to re-login again.